# A more systematic code for a natural problem in websites

Tags: python, pandas

It isn't hard to write an elementary code (after a `groupby` by `name`) by `for`, `while` and `...` for
the following problem. Is there a more systematic way of solving it by more advanced commands of `python`, `pandas` or `SQL` ?

In a website, users do actions 'enter' , 'exit' and 'purchase'

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Bob' , 'Alice', 'Ali', 'Bob', '...'] ,
                   'action' : ['enter', 'enter', 'enter', 'purchase' , '...'],
                   'time' :[4, 10, 12, 18, '...']})
```

We want to add next to purchases, the time that purchase takes:

`df1['T'] = ['','','',14,'...']`

To be more specific this times for each user are independent from other users.
consider a specific user and his\her actions:

```
action = ['enter' , 'exit' , 'enter' , 'purchase' , 'purchase',  'exit', 'enter', 'purchase', 'purchase', 'purchase', 'exit', 'enter']
time = [2 , 10, 32, 50, 60,    75, 100, 113,114,115,  140, 145  ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'action' : action, 'time' : time})
```

We want the following:

```
df2['T'] = ['' , '', '', 18,18, '' , '' , 10, 10 , 10, '','']
```

We consider the time of last purchase in each collection of successive purchases (may be only one) as a cut for presence of user in site (so we cut time to [2,60] and [60,115] and ignore actions of each user which are after last of his\her purchases). We subtract times from `exit` to `enter` that forms interval and we get times 36 and 30. Then we divide this time equally between successive purchases, if there is.

Comment: `T` is time from `df1` correct? why do you code `10` for the purchase value of `113-115` where is the user_id on `df2`? both very simple do in both SQL and python - former just needs a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY(..)` listing your crtierion and possibly a cross apply or standard join. - latter use `cumcount()` and your conditions and use `map` or `join` but your data doesn't marry up - i.e what are the keys you are joining against?

Comment: Yes. We want a number next to each `purchase` which show the time duration for that purchase. in `df1` we have one `purchase` by `Bob` for which `Bob` wad present in website from time 4 to time 18, and so we want 14 next that `purchase`. the question is about `df1`. `df2` is a subset of `df1` for actions of a specific user. Could you please write the answer explicitly? @Manakin

Comment: `df2` is action and time for a user. I didn't wrote the name column. In `df2` we have three successive purchases which takes time from 60 to 115 which is 55. but from time 75 to time 100 the user weren't in website. so total time for these there purchases is 55-25=30. so every of these bunch purchases takes 10 units of time.@Manakin